# Is it expected to pursue a PhD after being a pre-doctoral research assistant with a professor

Tags: phd, application, research-assistantship

Does being a research assistant but previous to being a doctoral student under one specific professor mean that you are expected to apply for a PhD with them as supervisor in the following year?

I assume there is no such demand but afraid it's acquiescent to some professors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such *general* expectation. The two are independent. Either the student might not apply or the professor might not accept them if they did.

But some professors will hope for such and perhaps "expect" it. That is an individual thing, however. It might be good to have a chat with them (not email - a chat).

Comment: If I hire student assistants I see that as giving them the opportunity to peek inside what it is like doing research. That way they can make up their own mind on whether it is something for them or not. Not wanting to enter academia is perfectly understandable. So I expect them to be curious about doing a PhD, but also that the decision has not been made yet.